# Set of single objects and pairs, how to treat elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an assignment, where we have to simulate Turing machine computation with something completely different and I have get into the point where I need some set to be defined like this:

$Q = \Gamma \cup (Q_{M} \times \Gamma)$

where $\Gamma$ and $Q_{M}$ are just some sets of single objects. So $Q$ contains single objects and also pairs. Is this valid? I don't remember that I have ever used something like this for 4 years on university, so I am not completely sure whether it is valid or not.

If it is valid, how to properly treat elements in formal definitions? For example, I want to specify some subset $A \subseteq Q$ that contains only elements that are pairs and they hold some predicate. Is it OK to do it like this?

$A = \{(x,y) \in Q | xRy \}$

Or do I have to be more specific and not forget about single object elements?

Comment: It's clear what your construction is, and your definition of $A$ *should* be clear. However, taken literally, there's a fine point, or corner case: what if $\Gamma$ itself contains an ordered pair? You want $\Gamma$ and $Q_M \times \Gamma$ to be disjoint, and there are various ways to guarantee that. If they aren't disjoint, just replace $\Gamma$ with something disjoint that's bijectable with it — say, $\{Q_M\}\times \Gamma$. And or, make the definition of $A$ a little more explicit: $A=\{(x,y)\in Q_M\times\Gamma\mid xRy\}$.

Comment: Thank you, I have completely forgotten about the case when $\Gamma$ contains ordered pair. I will consider doing $\{Q_{M}\} \times \Gamma$, I just need to write that down and try it on some simple cases to see the idea behind it. But you cheered me up by saying it is possible to have set of single objects and also pairs, because that means I have completed the proof :) Thank you once again.

Comment: You're welcome.  $\{Q_M\}\times \Gamma$ and $Q_M\times \Gamma$ are disjoint because $Q_M \notin Q_M$, (indeed, for all $x$, $x\notin x$).